# Semidirect product of free abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, semidirect-product, free-abelian-group

Consider the semidirect product
$$
G=\mathbb{Z}^n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}^m
$$
Is $ G $ always virtually abelian?

Is it the case that the abelianization of $ G $ is $ \mathbb{Z}^{n+m} $ if and only if $ G $ was already $ \mathbb{Z}^{n+m} $ to begin with?

If $ G $ is a nontrivial semi direct product can we conclude that the free rank of the abelianization $ G $ must be strictly less than $ n+m $?

I am especially interested in whether every semidirect product
$$
\mathbb{Z}^2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}
$$
is virtually abelian. If not are they all virtually nilpotent? All virtually solvable?

For example I believe that $ \mathbb{Z}^2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z} $ with respect to the semidirect product
$$
n \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1  \\ 1 & -d ​\end{bmatrix}^n
$$
is virtually solvable but not virtually nilpotent (or virtually abelian).

Comment: The semidirect product of two (free) abelian groups is always solvable; $\Bbb Z^n\rtimes \Bbb Z$ is nilpotent iff the eigenvalues of the matrix of action of $\Bbb Z$ on $\Bbb Z^n$ are roots of $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The semidirect product of ${\mathbb Z}$ acting on
${\mathbb Z}^2$ with action
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&1\end{array}\right)$$
is solvable but not nilpotent, and it is not virtually abelian.

Its abelianization if just ${\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought thanks! And do you know anything about more generally if abelianization of $ \mathbb{Z}^n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}^m $ always has rank strictly less than $ n+m $ (unless the product was trivial to begin with)?

Comment: If $f$ is the abelianization map, then the abelianization is generated by $f(\Bbb Z^n)$ and $f(\Bbb Z^m)$ and its rank cannot be bigger than the sum of ranks of these images. The rank of $f(\Bbb Z^m)$ is at most $m$. If the product is not direct,  the map $f$ restricted on $\Bbb Z^n$ has a non-trivial kernel. Indeed if for some $x\in \Bbb Z^n$ and $y\in \Bbb Z^n$, $z=x^y\ne x$ then $f(z)=f(x)$, so $f(z^{-1}x)=1$. Therefore the rank of $f(\Bbb Z^n)$ is strictly less than $n$. Hence the rank of the abelianization $<m+n$.